# Página do PHP não recebe dados via POST

Tags: php, html, php-7

Estou com um problema, por alguma razão meu script não recebe dados de um formulário, no entanto se eu envio o formulário para mesma página, ele recebe.

Segue formulário:

```
<form method="POST" action="/pjf/API/login.php" class="form-signin bg-white rounded border shadow p-5" id="formulario">
          <div class="text-center mb-4">
            <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">BEM-VINDO</h1>
            <p>Insira seus dados de login e senha corretamente.</p>
          </div>

          <div class="form-label-group">
            <input type="text" id="inputEmail" name="login" class="form-control btn-circle" placeholder="Login" required autofocus>
            <label for="inputEmail">Login</label>
          </div>

          <div class="form-label-group">
            <input type="password" id="inputPassword" name="pass" class="form-control btn-circle" placeholder="Senha" required>
            <label for="inputPassword">Senha</label>
          </div>

          <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary btn-block btn-circle" type="submit" name="submitt">ENTRAR</button>
          <p class="mt-5 text-muted text-center">Login Teste - 2020</p>
        </form>
```

Segue código PHP

```
<?php
  echo $_POST['login'];
?>
```

Sei que os dados são enviados pois se eu tiro o action, a própria página do formulário recebe e mostra o dado.

Comment: Quanto a pergunta, informe a estrutura de diretórios.

Comment: A pasta 'pjf' seria o diretório raiz.
A página do formulário está seguinte estrutura: 'pjf/log-in/auth/13350044395f1e6bc5ac5fb/l/0/'.
A página do receptor PHP está na seguinte estrutura: 'pjf/API/login.php'.

Comment: Cara, falta muitas variáveis para chegarmos a uma resposta! Mas sugiro colocar a URL completa no action: 'http://................/API/login.php"

Answer (score -1):

Amigo se vc não postar o caminho do diretório corretamente seu post não funcionará, seu action é *action="/pjf/API/login.php"*, mas vc informa a estrutura de diretórios seguinte *pjf/log-in/auth/13350044395f1e6bc5ac5fb/l/0/login.php*, supondo que o alvo do post estaria na pasta *0/* e supondo que o arquivo do seu form estivesse na pasta raiz seu action ficaria *action="log-in/auth/13350044395f1e6bc5ac5fb/l/0/login.php"*.
Espero ter ajudado...

Answer (score -1):

O problema aparenta ser o caminho utilizado no seu `action`. Quando você começa utilizando o carácter "/", isso indica a raiz do seu servidor. Ou seja se você estiver rodando no **localhost**, literalmente ele vai procurar em **http://localhost/pjf/API/login.php**

Você tem duas opções. A primeira trabalhar com o caminho relativo ou seja sem o carácter *"/"* no começo, assim a partir do diretório em questão ele vai procurar a dentro o caminho. Vamos supor que seu formulário esteja em "http://localhost/sistema/index.php", e  o `action` aponte para "pjf/API/login.php", seu caminho literal será "http://localhost/sistema/pjf/API/login.php".

A segunda opção seria colocar o `action` com o caminho completo, por exemplo "http://localhost/sistema/pjf/API/login.php" dessa forma não teria erro. Ressalto que essa segunda opção só seria inteligente usando uma função pra retornar o caminho, pois caso você venha a jogar isso pra um servidor na nuvem, teria que trocar o **localhost** em todos os lugares que usar esse termo. Dê preferência a usar o caminho relativo, primeira opção indicada.